# ¿Cómo puedo dibujar y rellenar de color zonas de un gráfico como las de la imagen (las partes sombreadas)? En R, con ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo mi gráfico con puntos en RStudio. Lo que quiero es dibujar zonas sombreadas como las que se muestran en la imagen, tanto la imagen A que son zonas unas sobre otras; como en la imagen B que son partes sombreadas individuales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Mario, la idea de la comunidad es dar respuestas concretas a preguntas concretas, te sugiero que pongas un ejemplo real de lo que estás haciendo, con el código, y una explicación del criterio que quieres para definir las áreas sombreadas. También sería mejor recibida tu pregunta si muestras lo que has investigado o intentado para resolver tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, para la próxima agregaré el código, expresaré lo que he intentado para solucionar mi problema y seré más específico, gracias por su aporte. En cuanto a lo que buscaba es prácticamente imposible hacerlo fácil en R, así que lo hice en un editor externo (GIMP). Saludos